# The action 'like' could not be found for TodoController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to add a like link to my first app, and I get this error: "The action 'like' could not be found for TodoController"
I've tried different things, but none of them worked.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root :to => 'home#index'
  resources :todo do
    member do
      put "like", to: "todo#like"
    end
  end
end
```

todo_controller.rb

```
class TodoController < ApplicationController


def index
    @todos = Todo.where(done: false)
    @todone = Todo.where(done: true)
end

def new
    @todo = Todo.new
end

def todo_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:name, :done)
end

def create
    @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
    if @todo.save
        redirect_to todo_index_path, :notice => "Your todo item was created!"
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def update

    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    if @todo.update_attribute(:done, true)
        redirect_to todo_index_path, :notice => "Your todo item was marked as done!"
    else
        redirect_to todo_index_path, :notice => "Your todo item wasn't marked as done!"
    end

def like
        @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    if @todo.liked_by current_user
        redirect_to todo_index_path, :notice => "Your todo item was liked!"
    else
        redirect_to todo_index_path, :notice => "Your todo item wasn't liked!"
    end
end




def destroy
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    @todo.destroy
    redirect_to todo_index_path, :notice => "Your todo task has been deleted!"
end
```

end
end

index.html.erb

```html
  <h2 class="big-title">Todo:</h2>
<% @todos.each do |t| %>
<p><strong><%= t.name %></strong>
<small><%= link_to "Mark as Done", todo_path(t), :method => :put %></small>
<small><%= link_to "Like", like_todo_path(t), method: :put %></small>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you put to link `@todos` instesd `t` `<%= link_to "Like", like_todo_path(t), method: :put %>`

Comment: I changed it, but I still get the same error.

Comment: If you want to see the generated paths for your app, you can run `rake routes` to find the path for the like action

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I've checked that several times, and it's the right path.

Comment: Is your TodoController class properly defined? You only show the action in your question.

Comment: I edited my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it!
The problem wasn't what I thought would be, and it was something very simple.

In the todo_controller, I just moved my "like" method over "update", and it worked.

Could someone tell my why it worked? I didn't know positioning was so important.

Comment: Currently it looks like you don't have closing `end` for `update` method, so `like` is not defined in the class context. Though you should have syntax error then. Can you double check that brackets, `def .. end`, `if .. end` are all correct?